# C++ Qt Table Rows Clearing When New Row Added

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qtablewidget

I am using the following code to create an object and then add a row to a qt table and populate it.
However after adding the first new row, the next time the button is clicked and a new row is added all but the first column of the row above are cleared.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

First Click Adds Row Just Fine
[image: First Click Adds Row Just Fine]

Second Click Clears Most Of The Row Above
[image: Second Click Clears Most Of The Row Above]

```
void MainWindow::on_btnAdd_clicked()
{
Inventory i;
int it = ui->cboItem->itemData(ui->cboItem->currentIndex()).toInt();
double q = ui->spinQnty->value();
int l = ui->cboLoc->itemData(ui->cboLoc->currentIndex()).toInt();

Item item(it);
Location loc(l);

i.insert(it,q,l);
i.setItem(item);
i.setQnty(q);
i.setLoc(loc);

QTableWidgetItem *newItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getItem_Name()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getCategory().getCatName()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem3 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(cn.dbl_to_str(i.getQnty())));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem4 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getLoc().getLocName()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem5 = new QTableWidgetItem();
newItem5->setData(Qt::UserRole,QVariant(i.getInv_ID()));

QIcon qi;
qi.addFile(QString::fromStdString("red_error_warning_icon.svg"));
newItem5->setIcon(qi);

int j = ui->mainTable->rowCount();

ui->mainTable->insertRow(j);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,0,newItem1);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,1,newItem2);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,2,newItem3);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,3,newItem4);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,4,newItem5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a function that adds rows in order to use it elsewhere in my program.
I found that I had column sort turned on in the ui file which was affecting my item inserts.
Here is the working code for adding rows which disables sorting while it adds items.

```
void MainWindow::addRow(int id)
{
ui->mainTable->setSortingEnabled(false);
Inventory i(id);

QTableWidgetItem *newItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getItem_Name()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getCategory().getCatName()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem3 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(cn.dbl_to_str(i.getQnty())));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem4 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getLoc().getLocName()));
QTableWidgetItem *newItem5 = new QTableWidgetItem();
newItem5->setData(Qt::UserRole,QVariant(i.getInv_ID()));

QIcon qi;
qi.addFile(QString::fromStdString("red_error_warning_icon.svg"));
newItem5->setIcon(qi);

int j = ui->mainTable->rowCount();

ui->mainTable->insertRow(j);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,0,newItem1);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,1,newItem2);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,2,newItem3);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,3,newItem4);
ui->mainTable->setItem(j,4,newItem5);
ui->mainTable->setSortingEnabled(true);
}
```